# How to implement multi-upload ques with Symfony2 and uploadify?

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony, multifile-uploader

I, have successfully implemented uploadify script into my app, files are being uploaded to `/web/uploads` folder.
I have entity `Order` witch can have multiple attachments `OneToMany-unidirectional` relation to `File` entity, uploadify is a part of `Order` form.
Now, I would like to transform ulpoaded files into `File` entity presisted to DB, and set it as related to `Order` that was created with form.

I suppose I have to add some kind of form ID to `Order` entity and persist it to DB, so uploadify can send this ID and I'll know witch files are related to witch form instance (Maybe use of CSRF token?)

In general, I have no clear idea of how to implement this feature, my english isn't very good, hope everyone will understand my intentions, I'll be thankful of any help or hints on implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this like that:

Each `Order` entity on construct gives an unique ID `base64_encode(microtime())` witch is persisted into DB, then on files form I get this ID from DB and pass it with uploadify `postData`, them I have clear link witch file was uploaded to witch `Order`